# How to set the mouse wheel scrolling speed in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to set the mouse wheel scrolling speed for an editor window? I think it's too fast. I'm running IntelliJ IDEA 8.1.4 on Mac OS 10.6.2.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found it. It’s called **idea.inertial.smooth.scrolling.unit.increment**

You can find the option in the Registry (Help / Find action / type Registry)

Comment: It took ten years, and it was worth the wait! (Currently using IDEA 2019.3 on a Mac)

Comment: Unfortunately that option seems to be gone again in 2020.2 :-( Was it renamed to something else?

Comment: @teomor, this option is gone on 2020.2

Answer (score 9):

Just in case any windows 10 users stumble upon here.

**Settings -> Mouse -> Choose how many lines to scroll each time**

**Set to 3.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is the only answer that helped!

Answer (score 8):

There is no option for this feature

Answer (score 8):

To get a precise scroll (very useful when comparing files), you can use **Smooth Scroller** plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8246-smooth-scroller

To scroll in larger steps, use **Fast-Scrolling** plugin:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling

You can use **both** plugins together, to make mouse scroll smooth and precise by default, whereas scrolling with *CTRL* key, makes it scroll faster.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Shree, no inner "how to", just a download links to those plugins from jetbrains (I installed it in pyCharm)

Answer (score 6):

Ok this is no answer for Mac OS, but for Linux. I didn't find the relevant question for Linux  yet, so I give a try here.

---

In `IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1.1` when I go to editor or console, mouse wheel scrolling means this: go down or up in the list by `3 lines` for each single wheel "snap in". I had no luck to find a an option in IDEA itself to adjust this number.

In my case this is too slow. To get this fixed, I did:

```
sudo apt-get install imwheel
```

Add the following to `~/.imwheelrc`, e.g.:

```
"^FocusProxy$"
None,      Up,   Button4, 10
None,      Down, Button5, 10

"^Firefox$"
None,      Up,   Button4, 3
None,      Down, Button5, 3

...
```

Please consider, that `10` is multipled by IDEA's `3`, so the resulting wheel speed is `30`.

Then, kill & restart `imwheel` with `imwheel --kill`.

Kill & quit (finalize the process) with `imwheel --kill ---quit`

`FocusProxy` is the window class, which was told to me by kill & restart in debug mode `imwheel --kill --debug`

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was totally stuck on the useless xprop WM_CLASS solution for finding the window name.

Comment: "Focus-Proxy" for me was also what I got for window name, but the rule seems to affect every window.

Comment: Oh, nvm - `--debug` also lets me see what regexes match and which ones don't. This works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I was uncheck in UI Options/Smooth scrolling, and i feel like it.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this fun plugin.
[https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling#:~:text=Fast%2DScrolling%20is%20a%20small,the%20hotkey%20to%20%5BALT%5D](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling#:%7E:text=Fast%2DScrolling%20is%20a%20small,the%20hotkey%20to%20%5BALT%5D).